# SCCM 2007: I've moved my site database, how do I now delete the old site system?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sccm

I have a small SCCM 2007 installation. It has two 'site systems', the primary site system (`SCCM01`) and the database server (`OLDSQL`).

For maintenance reasons, I had to migrate the database onto a new server (`NEWSQL`), running the same version of Windows and SQL (Windows 2008 R2 and SQL 2008 R2). I went through the correct steps for moving this site, using `preinst /stopsite` followed by the `ConfigMgr Setup` application to migrate the site over.

The new database works as expected, except for one thing. Under `Site Systems`, the old SQL server is still present and listed with the roles of `ConfigMgr component server`, `ConfigMgr site database server`, and `ConfigMgr site system`. The new database server is also listed, but only with the role of `ConfigMgr site system`.

I have the option to delete `NEWSQL` from the site systems, but not the option to delete `OLDSQL`, despite the fact that system doesn't exist any more. The `SMS_SITE_COMPONENT_MANAGER` also keeps throwing errors along the lines of:

```
SMS Site Component Manager failed to configure site system "\\OLDSQL" to receive SMS server components.
SMS Site Component Manager could not access site system "\\OLDSQL". The operating system reported error 2147942453: The network path was not found.
```

How do I move the site database server and component server roles from the old non-existent system onto the new system?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the steps in this article?

How to Move the Site Database http://bit.ly/JwUI4O

UPDATE: from http://blogs.technet.com/b/configurationmgr/archive/2010/01/28/configmgr-2007-how-to-move-the-site-database.aspx

> If you moved the Site Database to another server, you need to run the
>   Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager Setup Wizard on the
>   Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager 2007 Server to modify
>   the SQL Server  configuration to specify the new SQL Server name.
>
> 1. Ensure the primary site server computer account has administrative privileges over the new site database server computer.
> 2. Close any open Configuration Manager console connections to the site server.
> 3. On the primary site server computer, use the hierarchy maintenance tool (Preinst.exe) to stop all site services with the following
>      command: Preinst /stopsite.
> 4. On the primary site server computer, click Start, click All Programs, click Microsoft System Center, click Configuration Manager
>      2007, and click ConfigMgr Setup, or navigate to the .\bin\i386
>      directory of the Configuration Manager 2007 installation media and
>      double-click Setup.exe.
> 5. Click Next on the Configuration Manager Setup Wizard Welcome page.
> 6. Click Perform site maintenance or reset this site on the Configuration Manager Setup Wizard Setup Options page.
> 7. Select Modify SQL Server configuration on the Configuration Manager Setup Wizard Site Maintenance page.
> 8. Enter the appropriate SQL Server name and instance (if applicable) for the new site database server as well as the site database name on
>      the Configuration Manager Setup Wizard SQL Server Configuration page.
> 9. Configuration Manager Setup performs the SQL Server configuration process.
> 10. Restart the primary site server computer, and verify the site is functioning normally.
>
> Note: If you also need to move the Software Update Services Database
>   (SUSDB) you will need to stop IIS Admin Service, and Update Services
>   Service and follow Steps 1 and 2 above to detach, then move the
>   SUSDB.MDF and SUSDB.LDF files, then attach the SUSDB.MDF, in the new
>   drive location or on the new SQL Server 2005.

Comment: I did. No dice.

Comment: See the above edit.